# Finding email in mongoDB that doesn't appear in other documents

Tags: mongodb

So i have a bunch of documents in a collection that look like this:
[image: Image of document]

If i have a user logged in as `test@gmail.com`, i would like them to be able to see every user in which they aren't in a `chat` document with.

So for example. If i have another document like the following:
[image: Image of second document]

I would like `test@gmail.com` to see a chat on their screen with `user2@gmail.com`, but not with `john@gmail.com` since they aren't chatting yet.

What i need this for is to fill a drop down box with all the users that would fill the criteria of `john@gmail.com`

What would the mongoDB query be to get every user like `john@gmail.com`

Feel free to ask for clarification on anything!

Answer (score 0):

The query here is to find all chats in which "I" am a participant? If so:

`ChatCollection.find({ "participants.userEmail": "test@gmail.com" })`

will return all the chats I am part of. You can then find the names of all other participants with the usual array methods of your chosen language.

NOTE: I would advise an index on the "participants.userEmail" field.

To find all docs which don't feature "me", avoiding duplicates, use $not:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

e.g.

`ChatCollection.find({ "participants.userEmail": { $not: "test@gmail.com" } });`

This performs a logical NOT, returning all documents which do not match. This is importantly different to $ne, which is checking not equal on a particular field, which does not work in case of an array.

Comment: I need all email addresses where "i" am not sharing a `ChatCollection` with it. I should add that i would like to avoid duplicates if both of the emails in the chat have been found previously, if possible in MongoDB queries.

Comment: Apologies, I did not understand that requirement from the question. Please find my edited answer above.

Comment: I worked this out by myself luckily. What im mostly wondering is if there is a way to remove duplicates from the response that it gives me, within the mongodb query. Or if ill have to do that elsewhere.

Comment: In order to remove duplicates you’ll need to perform this as an aggregate query. Then you can perform a $group by _id such that you will only receive one of each duplicate. This will happen server side.

Comment: Sorry i cant work out how to use aggregates and groups, can you give me an example please?